# The folium of Descartes

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to understand the nature of points on the [Folium of Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folium_of_Descartes)
$$x^3+y^3=3xy$$

Converting to polar coordinates I get
$$r^3(\cos^3 \theta+\sin^3 \theta)=3r^2 \sin\theta\cos\theta$$ It seems to me that $r=0$ when $\theta=n\pi$ or $\theta=0.5\pi+n\pi$ or $\theta=0.75\pi+n\pi$. However, the graph of the curve only indicates the first two angles, and the points do not seem to approach the origin at the third case.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Just looking at the curve, there are no points corresponding to $\theta=\frac34 \pi$ or $\theta=-\frac14 \pi$, and as $\theta$ approaches these angles you have $r$ heading towards $-\infty$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite your equation this way:
$r^2\left(r(\cos^3 \theta+\sin^3 \theta)-3\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)=0$. This gives us two sets of points: 1) $r^2=0$ for any $\theta$ and 2)
$r(\cos^3 \theta+\sin^3 \theta)=3 \sin\theta\cos\theta$. The first set is just the origin. For the second set, $r=0$ only when either $\cos \theta=0$ or $\sin \theta=0$. When $\theta =\frac{3}{4}\pi+\pi n$ we have that $\cos^3 \theta+\sin^3 \theta=0$ and the equation becomes $0=-1.5$ so there are no $r$ and no points that satisfy this condition, that's why you see assymptotic behavior at these values of $\theta$. In other words, the origin is the only point where $\theta =\frac{3}{4}\pi+\pi n$.

Comment: Why is it that r doesn’t have to be zero when cos^3+sin^3=0? The righthand side becomes -1.5r^2

Comment: @hhs: I updated my answer, hopefully it explains it better now.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.